# In Javascript, how can I get the parent (or children) of a custom HTMLElement?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, how can I get the parent (or children) of a custom HTMLElement?
I want to find out the size and location of the parent element. I also want to attach a canvas.
please let me know if you want more information for this example question. I have tried several other ways to get the parent but they have all failed. I am new to HTML, CSS, an Javascript. I have mainly worked in C++ and Java. I look forward to any help you can provide.

Here is what I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>360 Video Player Component</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- <script src="js/three.min.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        class threeSixtyVideoElement extends HTMLElement {

            constructor() {
                super();
                const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
                console.log("hello");
                if (this.parentElement != null) {
                    console.log("parent = " + this.parentElement);
                } else {
                    console.log("Bummer");
                }
            }
        }
        window.customElements.define("threesixty-video", threeSixtyVideoElement);
    </script>
    <div class="firstLevelDiv" id="L1DIV1">
        <div class="secondLevelDiv" id="L2DIV1"> <p>class=secondLevelDiv id=L2DIV1</p> </div>
        <threesixty-video class="secondLevelDiv" id="L2DIV2"></threesixty-video>
        <div class="secondLevelDiv" id="L2DIV3"> <p>class=secondLevelDiv id=L2DIV3</p> </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The element might not yet have a parent when it is created.

Comment: And does that work?  `parentElement` is the right attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the parent element in your constructor. However, when your constructor is called i.e., the object is instantiated, the parent might be null because it has not yet been inserted in the HTML DOM.
You need to use the connectedCallback function, which is called after an element is inserted in the HTML DOM, instead of checking in the constructor.

```
connectedCallback() {
            console.log(this.parentElement);
        }
```

This connectedCallback function will execute when your element is inserted into the DOM and will give you the parent element.

Your class should look like this:

```
class threeSixtyVideoElement extends HTMLElement {
constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    console.log("hello");
}

connectedCallback() {
    console.log(this.parentElement)
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help .... on to the next issue ......